# Reading a csv file with a line feed in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I've a csv file with a line feed ('\n') in a column.
The rows are separated by a carriage return + line feed (\r\n)
The separator is ';' and quoted all.

I want to replace the line feed ('\n') in the column by a space.

I already tried to read the whole file and used split('\r\n') to get the rows but that doesn't work.

```
with open(r’d:\my_file.csv’,’r’) as fi:
    data = fi.read()
    lines = data.split(‘\r\n’)

    for line in lines:
        with open(r’d:\my_file.csv’,’a’) as fo:
        fo.write(line.replace(‘\n’, ‘ ’)

import csv

    with open(r’d:\my_file.csv’, ‘r’, newline=‘\r\n’) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=‘;’,quotechar='"')
        for row in csv_reader:
           n_row = row.replace(‘\n’, ‘ ‘)
    …
```

Is it possible to read the file line by line and using '\r\n' as a new line indicator?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Would be easier to help if you add the code that doesn't work.

Comment: @PatrickArtner : I've already tried that but it gives me an error due to the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains weird `’` and `‘` .. you also try to use `.replace()` on a row given to you by `for row in csv_reader:`. *That* `row` is a list of columns - nothing you can directly call `replace()` on.  You need to replace the newline inside each column of this row.

--

You try to read the file yourself - with quoting this is difficult. Using the  [module csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read and store the csv again is much easier:

**Write demo file:**

```
import csv

t = [["a", 2, "c\nd", 4], ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"], ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]]

# using the default seperator of: ',' - use delimiter=';' to change it
with open( "d.txt", "w", newline="") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    w.writerows(t)

# print files content
print(open("d.txt").read())
```

Filecontent:

```
"a","2","c
d","4"
"aa","bb","cc","dd"
"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"
```

**Read demo file, manipulate data and store in list**

```
data = []
with open("d.txt") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, quotechar='"')
    for row in r:
        data.append( [x.replace("\n"," ") for x in row] )

print(t)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
# original data
[['a', 2, 'c\nd', 4], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'], ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']]

# parsed and replaced data (some numbers are now strings, \n is replaced)
[['a', '2', 'c d', '4'], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'], ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']]
```

**Write modified data back to a new file:**

```
with open( "d_mod.txt", "w", newline="") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    w.writerows(data)   # modified data

# print new files content
print(open("d_mod.txt").read())
```

Modified filecontent:

```
"a","2","c d","4"
"aa","bb","cc","dd"
"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"
```